# Returning a value without an explicit return statement

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In JavaScript, falling off the end of a function returns `undefined`; if you want to return a value, you need to use an explicit `return` statement.

At least this was hitherto the case, but it looks like ECMAScript 6 will at least sometimes allow the `return` to be omitted.

In what circumstances will this be the case? Will it be related to the distinction between `function` and `=>` or is there some other criterion?

Comment: The `new` keyword already works in previous ES versions :-)

Comment: When will this change in ECMAScript 6 trickle down to javascript supported by modern browsers? Also, what do you mean `return` to be omitted? Can't return be omitted in current javascript: "In JavaScript, falling off the end of a function returns undefined"? Do you mean returning a value even if return is omitted? Please clarify.

Comment: @meewoK I mean the impression I get from what I've been able to find is that you can't write the successor function as `function (x) {x+1}` but you will be able to write it as `x => x+1`, but I don't know what the exact criterion for the difference is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The definitive material on this subject is the latest ES Harmony [specification draft](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3aspecification_drafts), and specifically the part derived from the [arrow function syntax proposal](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3aarrow_function_syntax). For convenience, an unofficial HTML version can be found [here](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-13.2).

In short, this new syntax will allow the definition of functions much more concisely. The ES spec draft has all the detail, I 'll explain very roughly here.

The syntax is

```
ArrowParameters => ConciseBody
```

The `ArrowParameters` part defines the arguments that the function takes, for example:

```
()                   // no arguments
arg                  // single argument (special convenience syntax)
(arg)                // single argument
(arg1, arg2, argN)   // multiple arguments
```

The `ConciseBody` part defines the body of the function. This can be defined either as it has always been defined, e.g.

```
{ alert('Hello!'); return 42; }
```

or, *in the special case where the function returns the result of evaluating a single expression*, like this:

```
theExpression
```

If this sounds rather abstract, here's a concrete example. All of these function definitions would be identical under the current draft spec:

```
var inc = function(i) { return i + 1; }
var inc = i => i + 1;
var inc = (i) => i + 1;
var inc = i => { return i + 1; };
```

As an aside, this new syntax is exactly the same *great* syntax that C# uses to allow the definition of lambda functions.